# Finding derivative with fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know the fundamental theorem says that:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \ dt = f(x)$$

But what is the reasoning behind this since:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \ dt = F(b)-F(a)$$

My question is what happens to the $a$ in the first equation? Do we just assume $f(a)=0$? Also why does $x$ always need to be an upper bound?

Comment: $f(a)$ has no dependence on $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you differentiate a constant (i.e. $F(a)$), it vanishes. However, the function which is explicitly dependent on $x$ does not vanish.
So, $\frac{d}{dx}(F(x)-F(a)) = f(x) - 0 = f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the FTC states: if $f$ is continuous at $c\in (a,b)$ then the function defined as $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$$ is differentiable at $c$ and its derivative is 
$F'(c)=f(c)$. If we can find some other function $g$ such that $f=g'$ then $F'=g'$ implies $F=g+k$ for some constant $k$. Since 
$$g(a)+k=F(a)=\int_a^a f(t)dt=0$$
then $k=-g(a)$ and then $F(x)=g(x)-g(a)$. In particular 
$$F(b)=\int_a^b f(t)dt=g(b)-g(a)$$
This result remains true even if $f$ is not continuous (it is known as the second part of the FTC).